# Convert.ToString(DateTime.UtcNow) unexpected beheviour?

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I have asp.net site (Framework 4.0), its working fine, recording the user login/logout time in SQM 2000 database. I used this method `Convert.ToString(DateTime.UtcNow)` to get system time.

Some time it saved "yyyy-MM-dd" format, its fine but some time "yyyy-dd-MM", so how to debug it, hosted site on shared environment, so I think the time format will consistent everywhere.

same use have both formats. So I am not able to reproduce it.

i.e. it saved todays date in "2012-03-01" && "2012-01-03",

Please let me know, whats issue with it?

Thanks,
Laxmilal Menaria

Comment: If you are storing the date in the database, why convert it to a string? I hope it's a datetime column!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the default culture of the server might change. You should use a specific culture object for any culture dependant conversions instead of using the default. For example:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("EN-gb");
string date = Convert.ToString(DateTime.UtcNow, culture);
```

(You can of course keep the `CultureInfo` object as long as is practical, and not create one for every use.)

Alternatively specify a custom format:

```
string date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd");
```

#### Edit:

I tried to look for an "SQM 2000" database to see what it was, but found nothing about it. If you mean Microsoft SQL Server 2000 database, then it's capable of storing dates as the `datetime` datatype, so you should not convert the date to a string in the first place.

Comment: I already have application level culture en-US in web.config, <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8"/>

so how it possible in different culture ?

Comment: The problem is most likely *not* that the default culture of the server is changing. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - it isn't very good idea to save date as string. Try to use date type in your DB.
 
Looks like that users runs `Convert.ToString(DateTime.UtcNow)` from different cultures. You can use approach provided by Guffa but if you try to use second variant you should remember that for some cultures it can be formatted as "2012/03/01" because framework recons  "-" as format symbol that should be converted to separator specified for user culture.
 
So I again recommend you to store date as date object in your DB.

Comment: Note that I used `'-'` in the format string, not `-`, so it will be the literal dash character, not interpreted as the date separator.

Comment: Thanks Guffa. Nice trick. But I still think that store date as string in DB is bad idea :)

Comment: Yes, of course he should use a date type if possible. I was thinking that he used some database solution that simply didn't support a date type, see the edit that I wrote in my answer.